# How to get custom claims of `FirebaseUser` on unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, jwt

I using firebase auth on unity for user login.

When user join, client send join request to my `my server` and `my server` will set custom claim(`userNumber`) to user.(Currently, Server using `firebase-admin-dotnet`)

After user joined, client re-login for refresh.
At this time, i want get custom claim in token. but i can't find relative method in `FirebaseUser` class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom claim access is missing from the Unity SDK as of v6.6 (Nov 2019). You can add a server function that returns the custom claims for the current user:

```
// Either use an existing User ID
UserRecord user = await FBAuth.GetUserAsync (uid);
return user.CustomClaims; // user.CustomClaims ["userNumber"]

// OR use a verified ID token
FirebaseToken token = await FBAuth.VerifyIdTokenAsync (idToken);
return token.Claims; // token.Claims ["userNumber"]
```

**Important:** If you use a billed-usage server, like Cloud Functions, this approach will incur billing charges, unlike a built-in Firebase method.

Other platforms (Android, iOS, web) have this method already (`getIdTokenResult`), so I submitted a feature request to Firebase to include it in a future version.